# Pulling out specific values from a string in Python

Tags: python, string, file

So I'm reading from a file some data on how long a program took to run. The text file looks like repeated "blocks" like this:

`real    1m49.296s
user    1m40.597s
sys     0m7.979s`

I need to pull out the minute and second values in the "user" and "sys" lines in order to sum them up. As of now, I have a for loop for the number of these "blocks" in the file and I'm reading through line by line, saving the real, user, and sys lines to different string variables. I don't think this is a great way of doing so, however, because it requires I hard-code the number of "blocks." Obviously I'm pretty new to this, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the code you do have? Even if you think it's not great, it at least demonstrates something that can be improved upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Regular expression` is your friend.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Check the match group section:

> (...)
>
> Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, and
>   indicates the start and end of a group;  the contents of a group can
>   be retrieved after a match has been performed,  and can be matched
>   later in the string with the \number special sequence, described
>   below. To match the literals '(' or ')', use ( or ), or enclose them
>   inside a character class: [(], [)].

Since you already know how to read the text file.
Below is an example showing how to parse the text and do the calculation

```
import re
foo = """real    1m49.296s
user    1m40.597s
sys     0m7.979s
"""
total_sec = 0
for item in foo.splitlines():
    m = re.search(r"(real|user)\s+(\S+)m(\S+)s", item)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3))
        total_sec += (float(m.group(2))*60+float(m.group(3)))
        print("total %f" % total_sec)
```

Result:

```
('real', '1', '49.296')
total 109.296000
('user', '1', '40.597')
total 209.893000
```